# C++ dynamic array of pointer to another class

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Hello i'm trying to create a dynamic array of pointer to an object `Student` from `Grades`class but i can't figure out how to declare it in the header

that's the header:

```
class Grades
        {
private:
    Student** array;
    int _numofStud;


public:


    Grades();
    Grades(const Grades& other);
    ~Grades();
```

and the grades constructor (i'm not sure it's right)

```
Grades::Grades()
{
    this->array = new Student * [2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        this->array[i] = NULL;
    }
    this->array[0]= new Student("auto1", "12345");
    this->array[1]= new Student("auto2", "67890");
    this->_numofStud = 2;
}
```

The probleme is that before it even enter to the constructor, it creating me an array of Size 5 in `Grades` because i have 5 elements in the Student constructor

```
Student::Student(const char* name, char* id)
{
    this->_numofgrade = 0;
    this->setName(name);
    this->setId(id);
    this->_grades = NULL;
    this->_average = 0;
}
```

And i can't add or modify this size

I want to put a default size of Grades to an array of 2 pointers to student object that i'll define as default then i'll have an other methods that add new Students by creating them and adding their pointers to the array
Th problem is i can't change the size of array and i don't understand why

I hope i was clear in my explanation thanks for your help

Edit:
[image]

that's the debuger and you can see when it's creating a new object Grades g1
it's creating an array of 5 instead off two
fill the 2 first as i asked for
and the 3 left i have no idea why they have been created and whats inside them

Comment: You would be far better of using a `std::vector<Student>` for your `array` member!

Comment: Related, I can't think of a reason in the posted code why you're using a pointer array *at all*. A `std::vector<Student>` would seem more appropriate, and bring the added benefit of being far closer to [RO3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) compliant.

Comment: "*before it even enter to the constructor, it creating me an array of Size 5*": I don't understand what you mean with this. What array are you talking about? Also what does "*5 elements in the Student constructor*" refer to? What are these "*elements*"?

Comment: Is your intention here to understand how a dynamically sized data structure, such as `std::vector` actually works? Do you know the size required in `Grades()` or do you want like a `addStudent(...)` function that can be called many times?

Comment: it's for a school project and we did't learn `std::vector`yet so i'm not sure i can use it
What i mean by "before enter the constructor" is that when i define `Student ** array`it's creating me automaticlay an array of size 5 and i can't understand how to modify this size
The 5 element in student refere to every "this->"

Comment: "The probleme is that before it even enter to the constructor, it creating me an array of Size 5 in Grades because i have 5 elements in the Student constructor" I am quite positive this is incorrect and it is not even remotely true. You need to use a debugger. Whatever is inside `Student` is irrelevant to the size of `array`.

Comment: @SabbanNoam I still don't know what you mean. There is no automatically created array and the members of `Student` are irrelevant. The shown code is correct (though bad style because of `new`, but that seems to be your instructor's fault). What problem are you experiencing when compiling and running it?

Answer (score 2):

OK, so to be clear, in any actual programs you should use `std::vector` or other containers, they have a lot of features I ignored here (being templates, supporting move semantics, not requiring a default constructor, etc.), a lot of saftey (what if a constructor throws an exception? What if I do `array.add(array[0])`?), while still being pretty well optimised for general purpose usage.

And you should also really look at `std::unique_ptr`, manual `new`, `delete`, is generally asking for leaks and other mistakes, in C++ a manual "free" or "delete" of any resource is almost never needed.

Also note in C++ `size_t` is often used for sizes/lengths of objects and containers.

So the basic idea of a dynamic array is it changes it's size based on current requirements, so `Grades()` can just start off empty for example.

```
Grades::Grades()
    : array(nullptr), _numofStud(0)
{}
```

Then when adding a new item, a new larger array is made, and all the existing items are copied (roughly what `std::vector::push_back(x)` does).

```
void Grades::addStudent(Student *student)
{
    // make a larger array
    Student **newArray = new Student*[_numofStud + 1];
    // copy all the values
    for (int i = 0; i < _numofStud; ++i)
        newArray[i] = array[i]; // copy existing item
    // new item
    newArray[_numofStud] = student;
    ++_numofStud;
    // get rid of old array
    delete[] array;
    // use new array
    array = newArray;
}
```

Comment: No need to declare the array the the header in private like i did ?
`class Grades
        {
private:
    Student** array;
   `

Comment: Yes you need the stuff in the header, I used the same two variables (`array` and `_numofStud`) you had already.

Comment: I made the same addStudent fonction but the problem is that when i make the newArray of size [numofStud +1] it's creating me a new array of size 5 
No matter what size i put for the `new Student*[_numofStud +1]`it's creating an array of size 5 
That's what i can't understand

Comment: I added a pic of the debug so you can see what i mean

Comment: C/C++ has no way for the user to determine "size of allocated array" from `new T[n]`, that is why you need a size variable. Whatever `_numofStud +1` is (for my code 1, 2, 3, etc.) is the number of elements that are *valid*. Looking at anything past that is undefined.